# Firebase user ID variable to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, firebase

Using Firebase, I am trying to display a user's profile information based on their user id. I can currently save data to the database under the users ID.

[image]

I am able to display the general information from hobbies, but when altering the variables to display the user's data the id is then null or uid undefined and i can't figure out why? The user is signed in, and can upload data using their id.

```
//Display Profile Information
(function(){                

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid;

if (user != null) {
uid = user.uid;  
}


const preObject = document.getElementById('object');
const list = document.getElementById('list');

//Displays Hobbies correctly, When changing 'object' & 'hobbies'
//to 'Users' & uid nothing is shown. 
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');
const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child('hobbies');

dbRefObject.on('value', snap=> {
    preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
});

dbRefList.on('child_added', snap => console.log(snap.val()));

};
```

**Alterations:**

```
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');
const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child(uid);
```

I am extremely grateful for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a `value` for `dbRefObject` which is pointed to the entire `Users` object and not a specific user's UID.

Try changing this:

```
dbRefObject.on('value', snap=> {
    preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
});
```

to this (dbRefObject changes to dbRefList):

```
dbRefList.on('value', snap=> {
    preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This will most likely work, but its not while my uid variable is still returning as undefined. Do you know why its doing that? The user is definitely logged in.

Comment: Sorry I missed that!

Your code looks right. The most likely reason I would expect `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` to be `null` is if you made the call before the signin call returned. Try putting this in the sign in callback and see what it writes to the console: console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);